# How to decrease the time of mapping a result or query to sql in .net?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core

I am making a call to a function in .net from angular js, the time it takes to get the response to angular from .net is more than 5 seconds. How can I make the mapping of the result of a sql query decrease in time, I have the following code.

```
List<CarDTO> result = new List<CarDTO>();
var cars = await _carsUnitOfWork.CarRepository.GetCarDefault(carFilter,true,_options.Value.priorityLabel);
result = cars.Select(car => _mapper.Map<Car, CarDTO>(car)).ToList();
```

Comment: Have you measured what part of you code consumes most of the time?

Comment: Apparently it is precisely in the snippet of code that I post, when mapping the result. Because if I do a direct query in the Swagger, the time is less than 1 second.

Comment: @josejuanriveragarcia what are the fields in your classes being mapped? may be try mapping them manually field by field and see if it is the mapper itself or fields are causing delay.

Comment: What have you done to pinpoint the exact cause of the bad performance? There's nothing in the snippet you've shown that seems poorly designed for performance. Have you looked at the many ways to performance investigate your application that you can find guides to? Downvoting for lack of details - there's nothing for us to go on.

Answer (score 2):

The code you have provided isn't expanded enough to identify a cause, but there are a number of clues:

Check / post the code for `CareRepository.GetCarDefault()`. The call implies that this is returning an IEnumerable given it is Awaited. It isn't clear what all of the parameters are and how they affect the query. As your database grows, this appears to return *all* cars, rather than supporting pagination. (What happens when you have 10,000 Car records, or 1,000,000?)

Next would be the use of Automapper's `Map` method. Combined with `IEnumerable` this means that your repository is going through the hassle of loading all Care entities into memory, then Automapper is allocating a duplicate set of DTOs into memory copying across data from  the entities.

Lazy loading is a distinct risk with an approach like this. If the CarDTO pulls any fields from entities referenced by a Car, this will trip off additional queries for each individual car.

For best performance, I highly recommend adopting an `IQueryable` return type on Repository methods and leveraging Automapper's `ProjectTo` method rather than `Map`. This is equivalent to using `Select` in Linq, as `ProjectTo` will bubble down into the SQL generation to build efficient queries and return the collection of DTOs. This removes the risk of lazy loading calls as well as the double memory allocation for entities then DTOs.

Implementing this with your Unit of Work pattern is a bit of an unknown without seeing the code. However it would look something more like:

```
var result = await _carsUnitOfWork.CarRepository
    .GetCarDefault(carFilter,true,_options.Value.priorityLabel)
    .ProjectTo<CarDto>(mapperConfig)
    .ToListAsync(); // Add Skip() and Take() to support pagination.
```

The repository method would be changed from being something like:

```
public async IEnumerable<Car> GetCarDefault( ... )
```

to

```
public IQueryable<Car> GetCarDefault( ... )
```

Rather than the method returning something like `.ToListAsync()`, you return the built Linq expression.

I.e. change from something like:

```
var result = _context.Cars.Include().Where(x => ...).ToListAsync();
return result;
```

to

```
var query = _context.Cars.Where(x => ....);
return query;
```

The key differences is that where the existing method likely returns `ToListAsync()` we remove that and return the unmaterialized `IQueryable` that Linq is building. Also, if the current implementation is Eager Loading any relations /w `.Include()` we exclude those. The caller performing projection doesn't need that. If the caller does need Car entity graphs, (such as when updating data) the caller can append `.Include()` statements.

It is also worth running an SQL Profiler to look at what queries are being run against the database server. This can give you the queries to inspect and test, as well as highlight any unexpected queries being triggered. (I.e. caused by lazy loading calls)

That should give you some ideas on where to start.